# How to set holoeverywhere slider menu width (addonSlider)?

Tags: android, android-layout, slidingdrawer, android-holo-everywhere, holoeverywhere

I'm having a bit of a problem setting the addonSlider() (aka Sliding menu) width for menu/shadow.

I looked inside the AddonSlider class and SliderMenu class and didn't find anything that refers to setting the width of menu/shadow.

The only thing regarding that i found was this:

```
private void attach(View view, int gravity) {
        if (view == null) {
            return;
        }
        final ViewGroup.LayoutParams initialParams = view.getLayoutParams();
        DrawerLayout.LayoutParams params;
        if (initialParams instanceof DrawerLayout.LayoutParams) {
            params = (LayoutParams) initialParams;
        } else if (initialParams != null) {
            params = new LayoutParams(initialParams);
        } else {
            params = new LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        }
        params.gravity = gravity;
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
        ViewParent parent = view.getParent();
        if (parent != null) {
            ((ViewGroup) parent).removeView(view);
        }
        requestDrawerLayout();
        mDrawerLayout.addView(view, gravity == Gravity.NO_GRAVITY ? 0 : -1, params);
    }
```

but messing a bit with this settings got me nowhere

Comment: you want to change the drawer width?

Comment: yes, i want to set the drawer width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally i got what i wanted. It passed me, but all i had to do is override the:

`<dimen name="menu_width">200dp</dimen>.`  attribute

Thanx to Prototik for that